# Facebook Auth Dialog: Aggregation Previews Not Showing Up

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I recently updated my Facebook Connect web application to use the new Auth Dialog, but am having trouble getting the Aggregation Previews to show up. When configuring the dialog, and I hit the "preview dialog" link, all looks well. But, when using it in practice during login, the right side of the Aggregation Previews are not there.

Any ideas? I know it's not much info to go on, but Facebook is not providing me with any sort of debugging info. Thanks!

[image: Auth Dialog Preview]

[image: Actual]

Comment: I reckon that we're going to need some code and further information to answer your query.  Perhaps a screenshot of the "right side of the aggregation previews not being there".  This will hopefully give us a clearer picture of the problem that you're facing.  I've looked at the docs [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/define-units/)

Comment: Added the two screenshots as per your suggestions. However, there is no code to review, since it's all within the Facebook configuration. Any way else I can add more info>

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: I was not asking for the permission "publish_actions".

As such, Facebook had no reason to show the Aggregate Previews section, because the user would never see those until we were authorized with the appropriate permission.

Another reason, as of this point in time before the Facebook Timeline is fully launched, the person you are logging in as needs to be a developer or these "publish actions" permission is ignored, and thus the Aggregate Previews section would not show up.